# Show $X$ and $Y$ are independent if we assume that $E[XY] = E[X] E[Y] $

Tags: probability, independence

Assume that $$E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$$ Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables taking two different values $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that X and Y are independent.

---

Note: I've spent a long time on this problem. I tried to use all the info given and arrived at a tautology. For that reason, I think there is no use in posting my attempt.

Comment: This is not true. What leads you to believe that it is?

Comment: I like how this gets downvoted, but some wally being like 'why do we give sin and cos names' - 42 upvotes.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I believe it is true in this case

Comment: @Omnomnomnom its a practice problem

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This is true for Bernoulli variables - and X Y basically are

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted the part about two values; the question makes sense. My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show it first for $a=0$, $b=1$ (Bernoulli variables).

In this case, $E(XY)= P(X=1,Y=1)=p_{11}$ and $E(X)=P(X=1)=p_{10} + p_{11}$
 $E(Y)=p_{01} + p_{11}$

So $E(X)E(Y)=E(XY)$ implies that $ P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1) P(Y=1)$. Show that this also is valid for the other joint probabilities - and hence $X,Y$ are independent.

Next, for general $a,b$ consider $U=(X-a)/(b-a)$ and $V=(Y-a)/(b-a)$. Show then that $X,Y$ uncorrelated implies $U,V$ uncorrelated. And $U,V$ independent implies $X,Y$ independent.

Comment: Why must we introduce U and V here? Is it necessary to use correlation here? I have not learned that yet.

Comment: Two variables are uncorrelated if and only if the expectation of their product equals the product of their expectation.

Comment: @Ryan I introduced UV to solve the problem as a generalization from a more specialized one (Bernoulli variables) which is itself important and well known (for jointly distributed Bernoulli -as well as for Gaussian- rv s, uncorrelation implies independence). You don't need to go that way. If you prefer, you can directly express the equality of expectations in terms of the joint probabilities (four values) and deduce that X Y are independent.